# Is there way to convert just some service methods in a WCF to webMethods? Or add webmethods to an existing WCF?

Tags: wcf, webmethod, uritemplate, webget

I have an existing WCF, which already has service methods available on it. I would like add some webMethods to this very same WCF to be accessed via a web browser.

Is this possible?

I see plenty of examples online on how to setup webMethods, the uriTemplate, etc, but nothing that clearly shows how to accomplish my above question.

Comment: yes, read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412196(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Problem is this that example does not show anything on how to setup the web.config file with endpointbehavior and service...which is where I believe my issue lies.

Comment: having REST endpoints for your WCF services might be more work than it's worth, why not simply create an MVC app and expose methods via controllers?

Comment: In this case I think your question has been already answered

Comment: Ricardo Pontual you are correct. Using the link you provided, I found that the underlying issue is that I was not setting my 'behaviorConfiguration' up correctly. Once addressed that issue, my solution worked for me.